# Android Beacon Library - Beacon scanning stops after ~30 minutes

Tags: java, android, altbeacon, android-9.0-pie

I am working on a indoor nav problem, and I am seeing beacon scans stop when the screen is locked.  I'm using Android Beacon Library 2.15.1.  Nothing in the release notes lead me to believe 2.15.2 will solve my issues.

I've done some searching.  I've found that I need set longScanForcingEnabled to true in [Android Beacon Library  #529](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/529).  So in my manifest I've included:

```
        <service android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService"
        tools:node="replace">
        <meta-data android:name="longScanForcingEnabled" android:value="true"/>
    </service>
```

And I found that in new versions of Android I also need to overcome the silly battery saving options that limit me to ~10 minutes I need to enable as a Foreground service as discussed in [Android Beacon Library 642](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/642).

```
        mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(mContext);
        BeaconManager.setAndroidLScanningDisabled(false);
        mBeaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
        mBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1000);    // 1 second interval for group of measurements
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod (mBeaconManager.getForegroundBetweenScanPeriod());    // // set background same as foreground
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod (mBeaconManager.getForegroundScanPeriod());    // set background same as foreground
        mBeaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(
                buildNotification(mContext.getString(R.string.android_beacon_library_title), mContext.getString(R.string.android_beacon_library_message)),
                R.id.beacon_service_id);
        mBeaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
```

The enableForgroundServiceScanning did get me past the 15 minute point, but not past the 30 minute point.

I'm seeing this happen on a Pixel 2 running Android Pie and a Nokia 7.1/androidone running Pie.

I haven't been able to find anything that would tell me what the next step is.  I would appreciate any available help.

**Sneak peak** - also on my docket is to determine when the Bluetooth health is bad enough to require a power cycle (assuming I can't prevent the issue).  BluetoothMedic isn't the full answer since we support all the way to API 18 (really 14, but 14-17 don't count).

Comment: Did you test after adding `<meta-data android:name="longScanForcingEnabled" android:value="true"/>` with the latest library version?  What happened?

Comment: I tested with version  2.15.2 now.  I would say that the results are not so good. After 39 minutes scanning quit entirely.  But even before that, at about the 20 minutes mark, it seem like it was skipping beacon reports.  I'm testing in a room with a relatively large number of beacons, 11 beacons in a 10m X 12m  room, each beacon set to transmit their advertisement beacon every 100 ms, yet I would see intervals of several seconds without and beacon reports. Until finally at the 39 minute mark all reporting stopped.

Comment: @davidgyoung Another side effect that I've just noticed is that before using enableForegroundServiceScanning whenever I would unlock the phone it would start scanning again immediately as soon as the screen came on.  I didn't even have to go to the app.    When I include enableForegroundServiceScanning  scanning does not restart after it had quit.I have to relaunch the app entirely.

Comment: This gets pretty complex and can be very hard to troulbeshoot depending on all the code customizations involved.   I'd suggest repeating your tests on the Pixel with the library [reference application](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) (with the foreground service setup block uncommented) and let me know what you see.  For the Nokia 9.0 case, please see [this post](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/807).

Comment: @davidgyoung Thanks, I'll take a look.  I meant to mention this in my original question, and forgot - sorry -  haven't done any customization to the beacon library.  In my Gradle file I have included in the dependency section:  implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.15.2'

Comment: @davidgyoung I just commeted on Nokia post - I'm joew46167 over there.